# How to modify SharePoint list settings to allow Group Only listings using AD?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Sorry if the title is unclear, but what I am trying to do is get my site to show only the AD groups (it has options for Person Only, and Person and Groups), I would love to have a way to modify this for a "Groups Only" option. Is this possible?

(SharePoint 2013, if that matters for this)